# windbg dump : path of loaded dll which only shows dll name

Tags: dll, windbg

I am trying to debug issues with dll version and paths.

I have a dump which shows this output for `lmfsm` which shows no path for few dlls.
Some of these dlls are app specific so i know they should be coming from same folder as `MainEXE` but i am not sure about others.

There is no path shown for `dll present in same dir as main exe` (dllPresentInSameDirAsMainExe.dll) and `dll coming from gac` (dll_from_gac.dll).
So, which dll is being picked up for `System.IO.COmpression.dll` which is present in my local `MainEXE` folder as well.

```
0:000> lmfsm
00000000`00220000 00000000`00228000   MainEXE D:\ABCPATH\MainEXEPkg.Code.1.0.0.20200323.1\MainEXE.exe
00000000`1aab0000 00000000`1ac3c000   dllPresentInSameDirAsMainExe dllPresentInSameDirAsMainExe.dll
00000000`1db50000 00000000`1dbcc000   dll_from_gac Dll.From.GAC.dll
00000000`20350000 00000000`2036e000   System_IO_Compression System.IO.Compression.dll
00007ffb`d0250000 00007ffb`d025e000   System_IO_Compression_FileSystem_ni C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.IO.Cf61e09c5#\c4e0a673a512f8626f9b499f8574dc90\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.ni.dll
00007ffb`d7700000 00007ffb`d8344000   System_ni C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\66a8a818dfb2a81d684cd89cd3b83a80\System.ni.dll
```

So, how to find the path of `System.IO.Compression.dll` loaded in the process dump ?

Comment: Whatdoes `lmDvmSystem_IO_Compression`return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinDbg help says:

> f
>
> Displays the full image path. (This path always matches the path that is displayed in the initial load notification, unless you issued a .reload -s command.) When you use f, symbol type information is not displayed.

And indeed, a `.reload -s` seems to fix the problem:

```
0:000> lmf
start    end        module name
00f50000 00f58000   DebuggingEnumDefinition DebuggingEnumDefinition.exe
71640000 71692000   MSCOREE  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSCOREE.DLL
74e50000 74eef000   apphelp  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll
751a0000 7539e000   KERNELBASE C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNELBASE.dll
759a0000 75a80000   KERNEL32 C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNEL32.dll
777c0000 7795a000   ntdll    ntdll.dll   

0:000> .reload -s
......
0:000> lmf
start    end        module name
00f50000 00f58000   DebuggingEnumDefinition C:\...\bin\Debug\DebuggingEnumDefinition.exe
71640000 71692000   MSCOREE  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
74e50000 74eef000   apphelp  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
751a0000 7539e000   KERNELBASE C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
759a0000 75a80000   KERNEL32 C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.dll
777c0000 7795a000   ntdll    C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```